# How can I change the color of the icon when its pressed

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change color of the icon when its pressed. I tried this code:

```
Consumer<ProductController>(
                        builder: ((context, value, child) {
                          // log('${value.products[0].results?.length.toString()}');
                          if (value.products.isNotEmpty) {
                            return Container(
                                height: maxHeight * 0.3,
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: value.products[0].results!.length,
                                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                    return Card(
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        title: Text(value
                                            .products[0].results![index].name!),
                                        leading: IconButton(
                                          icon: const Icon(Icons.add),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              var ids = value.products[0]
                                                  .results![index].id!;
                                              if (productIds.contains(ids)) {
                                                productIds.remove(ids);
                                              } else {
                                                productIds.add(ids);
                                                isSelected = true;
                                              }
                                              // productIds.add(value.products[0]
                                              //     .results![index].id!);

                                              print(
                                                  "products=>>>> $productIds");
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                        trailing: IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(
                                            Icons.done,
                                            color: isSelected == true
                                                ? Colors.blue
                                                : null,
                                          ),
                                          onPressed: () {
                                            setState(() {
                                              productIds.remove(value
                                                  .products[0]
                                                  .results![index]
                                                  .id);
                                              print(productIds);
                                              isSelected = false;
                                            });
                                          },
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ));
                          } else {
                            return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                          }
                        }),
                      ),
```

I took bool variable inside state class. (Stateful widget)

```
bool isSelected = false;
```

Here I know I am doing it wrong. Like when its pressed I am making bool isSelected=true thats why all the remaining lists are also getting selected. But I can't find the logic behind this.

So, How Can I make this work. When its selected only that selected one will be colored, others will remain same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to be able to do that, you have to create a selectedIndex variable:

```html
int? _selectedIndex;
```

inside your onPressed, store the index in your '_selectedIndex`:

```html
onPressed:(){
_selectedIndex = index;
//your other codes...
}
```

then to change the color, you compare if selectedIndex  == index:

```html
                       trailing: IconButton(
                                          icon: Icon(
                                            Icons.done,
                                            color: _selectedIndex == index
                                                ? Colors.blue
                                                : null,
                                          ),
```

Comment: It only works for one item. I need to select all of the selected ones

Comment: `So, How Can I make this work. When its selected only that selected one will be colored, others will remain same.` this is your question and it is what i've answered. if you are looking for more, you have to create another question and clearly define what you are trying to do and what you are trying to achieve. i cant answer something that is not asked.